# ubuntu 22.04 reduce padding on dock icons

Tags: gnome, icons, 22.04, themes, dock

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and noticed that the padding between the icons on the dock bar seems excessive. See image below.

I poked around in the dconf-editor under org/gnome/shell/extensions, but didn't see anything about the margin or padding between the dock icons. I also tried some suggestions I found regarding changing the padding in some of the desktop theme .css files, but that information seemed old and outdated, and changing padding in them had no effect.

Is there something else that affects the dock padding?

[image: Ubuntu Dock with too large icon padding]

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the issue for this. It is your shell theme. I was using Arc as well and switching the shell theme back to the default one fixed the problem.
Updating or even reinstalling the theme did not fix the problem.

I assume the issues lies withing some styling rules specified in the theme.

Comment: I switched to the Yaru-Blue-Dark in Tweaks and that looks more normal.

Comment: The file you need to edit is `/usr/share/themes/*yourtheme*/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`.  The class for the top bar (which is your taskbar) is called `#panel`.  Not sure which child element controls the padding/margin/spacing...